# Make response when foreach is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

```
data.forEach(function(shelf){  
  books.find({"shelfid":shelf.id},function(book){
   //book1,book2,book3
  })
});
```

Each shelf has an id, and i find all books which has those id's.
So assume that this method finds 3 books, how do i response all those
books at the same time, when the foreach is completed.

Comment: how do i know if the for each is completed?

Comment: If you have several async methods, I'd suggest using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) for node.

Comment: You could use [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: Isn't there like a million such questions on SO already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551499/simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript

Comment: You should be using the `$in` operator anyway if this is really mongo/mongoose ... `books.find({shelfid: { $in: [ shelfIds ] }}, function(...){})`

Answer (score 1):

The [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) is perfect for this:

It basically iterates through each one and allows you specify a function to run after they are all run.

```
var arr = [];
async.each(data, function (fd, callback) {
    books.find({"shelfid":fd.id},function(book){
        arr.push(book);
        callback();
    });
}, function(err){
    // this runs once they've all been iterated through.
    // if any of the finds produced an error, err would equal that error
    // books are in the arr array now.
});
```

## EDIT

As WiredPrairie points out, doing this makes more sense:

```
 books.find({shelfid: { $in: [shelfIds] }}, function(books){
     // do stuff with books.
 })
```

Comment: isn't it possible without using a module?

Comment: @hackio updated answer to include a way to do it without a module.