# How to loop in node js, wait until each iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I have a function:

```
var third = function(classes){
  for (var i = 0; i <= (classes.length-1); i++) {
       var Myurl = classes[i];

       return function(Myurl){
          request(Myurl,  function(err, resp, body) { 
             if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $("#item_details dl").each(function() {
                   var Values = [];
                   var New = [];

                   Values=$(this).find("dd strong").text();

                   New = Values.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"");
                   AllLinks.push(New);
                });

                console.log(AllLinks);
             };
          })
       }(MyUrl);

  };
};
```

The problem is when I do the above I only get the result of first loop element `(i=0)` in the `console.log(AllLinks)`. How do I properly loop in node? I am new to node so any comments are much appreciated!

EDIT:
If I define `AllLinks` in `request` then it seems to work, but not in correct order...

```
var third = function(classes){
      for (var i = 0; i <= (classes.length-1); i++) {
           var Myurl = classes[i];

            (function(Myurl){
              request(Myurl,  function(err, resp, body) { 
                 if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    AllLinks=[];
                    $("#item_details dl").each(function() {
                       var Values = [];
                       var New = [];

                       Values=$(this).find("dd strong").text();

                       New = Values.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"");
                       AllLinks.push(New);
                    });

                    console.log(AllLinks);
                 }(Myurl);
              })
           };

      };
    };
```

Comment: async library https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks, I am a node beginner, so you maybe can provide an example about how the above function should be changed? best regards

Comment: Why do you want to return call result return function(Myurl){...}(MyUrl);? 
In certain scenarios it might be enough. 
Otherwise you might want to try promises or async library

Comment: @Igor how do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how you implement request but if you drop 'return' you'll most likely be able to call all your urls from classes. If you want to wait for all calls to succeed async.js sounds like your choice.

Comment: I think the solution is much simpler. Instead of return function in the loop, remove return and have it be only function

Comment: @AmmarCSE that gives not correct results...

Comment: @user1665355, where is AllLinks intialized/defined?

Comment: @AmmarCSE they are initialized in the global environment, outside of the function.

Comment: @user1665355, ok, what results are given when you try my answer?

Comment: @user1665355, they will not be in any gauranteed order because request() is asynchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major problem (apart from 'return') is that assuming request performs asyncronous operation your function returns when request is not completed and thus log contains no update.

You have two strategies in general:

1. call your code without 'return' as in the example above. This case
   all your requests will be eventually done but you have no control
   over when. It works well when you don't need them all to proceed,
   e.g. process AllLinks afterwards
2. Use any technology that supports waiting until all your calls are completed (async.js or promises). For example here [Simplest way to wait some asynchronous tasks complete, in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551499/simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript)

Thus you need:

```
function appendResultToItems(url, callback) {
 request(url,  function(err, resp, body) { 
   if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     $("#item_details dl").each(function() {
       var Values = [];
       var New = [];

       Values=$(this).find("dd strong").text();

       New = Values.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"");
       AllLinks.push({result:New, url: url});
       callback();
     });
 });
}

var calls = [];

classes.forEach(function(Myurl){
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    appendResultToItems(Myurl, callback);
  });
});

async.parallel(calls, function() {
  console.log(AllLinks);
});
```

Comment: Great answer, please see my edit. Is that what you mean, the edit code works but AllLinks are not in correct order...

Comment: You can't have them in order this case. What you can do is to write results by url or classes index and then reorder them

Comment: Btw, what is "callback" function in the example above?

Comment: It's the most simple way of notifying the function has completed. Normally it is called with result and/or error as parameters

Comment: So the callback is asyncsCallback you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Callback pattern is a default way of handling async calls in node. At the same moment it's just a function accepting some parameters according to convention and not of any specific type. For example in the last three lines of my example 'function' is a callback function.

Comment: What I meant was, see the link http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice. In the comment field, a guy wrote: "One slightly nit-picky thing is the naming of everything callback. It took me a few minutes to grock that the callback being used in those spots was actually the async module's callback and not meant to be one of mine."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78919/discussion-between-igor-and-user1665355).

Answer (score 1):

Use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries)#eachSeries to apply an asynchronous function to each element of a collection

Comment: thanks, but do you have an example of how the above function should be changed? I am a node beginner...

Comment: @user1665355 on async.js you will find more than examples

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are using **return** within the loop. If you simply use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
var third = function(classes){
  for (var i = 0; i <= (classes.length-1); i++) {
       var Myurl = classes[i];

       (function(Myurl){
          request(Myurl,  function(err, resp, body) { 
             if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $("#item_details dl").each(function() {
                   var Values = [];
                   var New = [];

                   Values=$(this).find("dd strong").text();

                   New = Values.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"");
                   AllLinks.push(New);
                });

                console.log(AllLinks);
             };
          })
       })(MyUrl);

  };
};
```

`AllLinks` will be correctly generated.

Comment: that does not give the correct results unfortunately! AllLinks are not correct...