# Database call in a function without callback with Node.js and Postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, connection-pooling

I'm trying out the framework node.js on one of my projects.
I'm really seeing some good advantages on what they called "event-driven, non-blocking I/O model" however if my project there are some moments where I don't necessarily want to have some asynchronous calls and to be able to several operation before launching some asynchronous call.

Especially when I  want to do  some factorization and create some functions.

Typically I have the following case:
I know that in several part of my program I have to check if a media is existing in my database for a given string or id.

So as a guy who tried to stay organize I want to create a function that I will call each time I need to check this.
However, I did not find the way to do that  with node.js and pg (the npm PostgreSQL library (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/) . Indeed, there is always a callback in the function and the return is null because of the callback. Here is an example below

```
/*
    Function which is supposed to check if a media existing
 */
function is_media_existing (url_or_id){
    log.debug("is_media_existing : begin of the function", {"Parameter" : url_or_id});
    pg.connect(connectionstring, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            log.warning("is_media_existing : Problem with Database connection", {
                "Parameter": url_or_id,
                "Error": err
            });
        }
        if (isNaN(url_or_id)) {
            // Case is parameter is not a number (string)
            var query = client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM media WHERE url = $1::string ', url_or_id);
            query.on('error', function (error) {
                log.warning("is_media_existing : Problem with Database query (connection to db passed but not query " +
                    "", {"Parameter": url_or_id, "Error": error});
            });
            return query;
        } else {
            // Case is parameter is a int
            log.debug("is_media_existing : Type of Parameter is a string");
            // Case is parameter is not a number (string)
            var query = client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM media WHERE id = $1::id ', url_or_id);
            query.on('error', function (error) {
                log.warning("is_media_existing : Problem with Database query (connection to db passed but not query " +
                    "", {"Parameter": url_or_id, "Error": error});
            });
            return query;
        }
    });
}


// Executing the function 
var test = is_media_existing("http://random_url_existing_in_db");
// test is always null as the return is in a callback and the callback is asynchronous
```

i have the feeling my question is touching the core concepts of node.js, and perhaps my approach is wrong and I apologize in advance.
I know it's not good to wait for a response before doing something.
But what's the alternative? How can I factorize my code into functions when I need some functionalities in several part of my code?

So if there would be anyone who could explain how to do that with a best practice of programming it would be great.

Thanks

Anselme

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10551499/1172714) StackOverflow question help?

Comment: Thanks dsh your proposal. However after viewing your link, I'm more looking for synchronous solution. Or what would be best the way to factorize such a functionality!

Comment: There is no synchronous solution unless you want to block your execution thread. This may interest you https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

Comment: Use of promises is a good approach to your tasks. Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Cody says, you probably dont want to do synchronous function.

The way you should handle the situation in your example is to pass in your own callback like this

```
function is_media_existing (url_or_id, callback){
```

and then instead of `return query;` use your callback like this-

```
callback(query);
```

or probably better to follow the node convention for callback functions to have two parameters `(err, result)` so your callback would look like this

```
callback(null, query);
```

Here is a rework of your sample

```
function is_media_existing (url_or_id, callback){       /* callback(err, result) */
    log.debug("is_media_existing : begin of the function", {"Parameter" : url_or_id});
    pg.connect(connectionstring, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            done(err);
            log.warning("is_media_existing : Problem with Database connection", {
                "Parameter": url_or_id,
                "Error": err
            });
            return callback(err, null);     
                /* note that this return is simply used to exit the connect's callback and the return value is typically 
                 * not used it is the call to callback() that returns the error value */
        } 
        var qrystr;

        if (isNaN(url_or_id)) {
            log.debug("is_media_existing : Type of Parameter is a string");
            qrystr = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM media WHERE url = $1::string;';
        } else {
            qrystr = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM media WHERE id = $1::id;';
        }
        client.query(qrystr, [url_or_id], function(err, result){
            done();
            if(err){
                /* .. */
            }
            callback(err, result);
        });
    });
}


// Executing the function 
var test = is_media_existing("http://random_url_existing_in_db", function(err, result){
    if(err){

    }else {

    }
});
```

If you end up with a hard nest of callbacks, promises are really worth looking into.

Comment: Dave, thank you so much for the enlightenment and the inputs on best practices to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really *do* want a synchronous call. The problem with synchronous calls in node is that it stops the entire process from doing *anything* while a synchronous function is running as it will stop the event loop. As an example lets say your sync function takes 2 seconds to complete. Your server will then do *nothing* for 2 full seconds. That 2 seconds includes *everything* (accepting new connections, everything else, etc). The reason blocking functions don't exist is because they are (*very*) bad. Here is an example how your function will react in an async manor.

```
is_media_existing("http://random_url_existing_in_db", function(exists){
  if (exists){
    //do stuff
  } else {
    //do this other stuff
  }
});
```

Then within `is_media_existing` you will need to call that callback function when your query completes.

```
//psuedo
function is_media_existing(url, callback){
  query('select COUNT(*) as count FROM media WHERE id = $1::id '. [url], function(err, result){
    if (err)
      callback(false)
    else
      callback(result.count > 0)
  })
}
```

Comment: Cody, Thank you very much for your input, you were the first one to answer but Dave gave a pretty good completion, but thanks for your explanations which helped me a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the new ES6 plus async stuff and babel its simpler.  You can `npm i -g babel` `npm i babel-runtime` then compile and run the following with `babel test.js --optional runtime --stage 2 | node`.  Please read the following example carefully to see how to adapt it to your use case:

```
let testData = [                                                
  { id: 0, childIds: [1,2]},                                    
  { id: 1, childIds:[] }                                   
];                                                              

function dbGet(ids) {                                           
  return new Promise( r=> {
    // this an example; you could do any db
    // query here and call r with the results                                    
    r(ids.map((id) => { return testData[id];}));
  });                                                           
}

async function dbExists(ids) {                              
  let found = await dbGet(ids); 
  return (found && found.length>0);                                               
}                                                               

async function test() {                                         
  var exists = await dbExists([0]);                              
  console.log(exists);                      
}                                                               

test().then(f=>{}).catch( e=> {console.log('e',e)});
```