# Node.js - load data and then hit urls - async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I am new at node.js, so please be patient :)

What I need to do:

- load from url Ids of users
- Hit another url for every ID

What am I doing wrong?

```
var http = require('http');
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();

url = 'http://example.com/api/get-users';

client.get(url, function (data, response) {
    if (data.status == 'OK') {
      users = data.users;

      users.forEach(function(item) {
        newUrl = 'http://example.com/generateStats/' + item;
        client.get(newUrl, function(data, response){
          console.log(data);
        });
      });
    }
});
```

The value of `users` is: `[1,2,4,5,7,...]`

Nothing in `forEach` is executing, why?

Comment: Coul you check if the if block is executed? I think it should be "response.status == 'OK'". Also create users as a new var and don't write it into the global scope "var users = data.users;". This can cause unexpected errors like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `status` in `data` nor `response` so it never go inside the if block. To handle errors with `node-rest-client`, you have to listen to the `error` event:

```
var http = require('http');
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();

url = 'http://example.com/api/get-users';

client.get(url, function(data, response) {
  // if there is an error, this function is not executed
  var users = data.users;

  users.forEach(function(item) {
    newUrl = 'http://example.com/generateStats/' + item;
    client.get(newUrl, function(data, response) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('something is wrong: ' + err.code);
});
```

There is a `response.statusCode` though, it returns an http code like 200.

Comment: My json file:{"status": "OK", "users": [1, 4, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43]}. But console.log(data) returns '<Buffer >' ... Why?

Comment: @Michal Ah, my bad, `data` is a Buffer object, just do `data = data.toString()` to get a JSON and you'll be able to check `.status` on it. This `node-rest-client` is weird, most of modules detect JSON and don't return a Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)
Check this answer: [simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551499/simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript#answer-10552398)