# Flush all active requests to mongodb from node before closing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to finish all active requests to mongodb from node when I need to gracefully shutdown the application (control+c / exceptions). I have tried using the `.close` method, which closes the connection just fine, but does not seem to wait for active requests to complete. The solutions I have seen appear to just keep a counter of live requests. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Please check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes

Comment: I am trying to shut down my node application, not mongo

Comment: Ah you want a way to gracefully shut down Node... and make sure all mongo requests get dealt with?  Or all requests in general?

Comment: @sova I'm trying to make sure that all mongo requests that I've fired off to mongo get dealt with on mongo before I close the connection and shut down the Node server.

Comment: In that case I think you can use Promises to ensure that certain tasks are completed before your program is cut/exited/terminated.    Perhaps check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551499/simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript