# AngularJS and async calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm an AngularJS promises novice and getting really frustrated on how to implement it. I'm hoping somebody here can help me out.

I have the following client-side code:

```
// Pass result to ng-csv directive.
$scope.generateEmployeeData = function () {
        $scope.employeename = empName;
        $http.get('/api/employee-information/download').then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            ToastFactory.error({
                title: "Oops!",
                text: "Something went wrong while downloading employee data.",
                icon: "exclamation-sign"
            });
        });
    }
```

... and the ff. server-side code:

```
// Download Employee data (.../api/employee-information/download)
exports.downloadEmployee = function (req, res) {
    var tempCtr = [];

    var dlPromise = EmployeeInfo.find({}, function (err, results) {
        var tempCtr = [];
        if (err) { return err; }

        console.log("dlpromise in");
        return results;
    });

    q.all(dlPromise)
        .then(function (results) {
            _.forEach(results, function (item) {
                tempCtr.push({
                    employeeID: item.employeeID,
                    employeeName: item.employeeName
                });
            });
        });

    console.log("tempctr out");
    console.log(tempCtr);

    return res.json(tempCtr);
}
```

When I checked my logs, I saw that `console.log("tempctr out")` was called first before `console.log("dlpromise in")`, and I get that it's because the process is asynchronous. That's why I used `q.all` (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551499/simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript)), because I thought that it would resolve `dlPromise` first before going inside `then()`. But it didn't work. What am I missing? Is my understanding of AngularJS' promises skewed in general?

I've been trying to solve this for a long time without any success. Please help.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I added a console.log after `console.log("dlpromise in");`. This is the result:

```
dlpromise in
[ { _id: 58c7b885db0afd48ee427a73,
    employeeID: '12349876',
    employeeName: 'Tester'}]
```

Comment: What does the api return? It looks like you are downloading something, what content type are you sending the response with?

Comment: console.log("tempctr out"); is not into the .then(), see this link about promises: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: @MarcusH Please see updated question.

Comment: @Groben Thank you for the link. This line definitely hit home: "Many of us are using promises without really understanding them." Will definitely read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with the server-side code, but I'm assuming it's NodeJS?

I think you could change the code to something in the lines of this (assuming res.json(tempCtr) sends the response data):

```
exports.downloadEmployee = function (req, res) {
    EmployeeInfo.find({}, function (err, results) {
        var tempCtr = [];
        if (err) { return err; }

        _.forEach(results, function (item) {
            tempCtr.push({
                employeeID: item.employeeID,
                employeeName: item.employeeName
            });
        });

        console.log("tempctr out");
        console.log(tempCtr);
        res.json(tempCtr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yep, it's node.js. This was what I tried earlier. What happened was it called `tempctr out` first before going back to do the `_.forEach` function. Client-side controller got an empty response.

Comment: Using this code `tempctr out` should not run before `_.forEach`, I can't say if the response is empty though. Did you try it?

Comment: I see, I'll give it another shot. :)

Comment: Finally it worked! Now I don't get why `q` didn't work in this case...but anyway. Thank you so much! :)